# How do I insert special formatted text from VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

This might be a very simple question with a hopefully simple reply. I have been googling for ages, and I just cannot seem to figure it out.

I need to insert some special formatted text from VBA, as the text inserted depends on 1 out of four 4 answers to a dropdown menu.

[A picture of what I want to insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faAwm.png)

As you can see on the picture, the user chose 'SM-1'. That means the below three requirements below has to be inserted *in that format.*

So all the balck text has to be text that is automatically inserted, and all the red text has to be inserted as FormFields that the user can write text in.

I really hope you guys can help out! Tell me if I'm not being specific enough and I will elaborate. :)

Comment: If you are creating a template you can use Building Blocks/Quick Parts. You may even be able to use a Building Block Gallery Content Control (find it on the Developer tab) that will enable the user to select what they need without using VBA.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I will take a look at it, thank you.